# Prove $1 > 0$ in ordered field

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

My proof of $1>0$ in the ordered field $F=\mathbb{R}$ seems too simple, but maybe it's correct?

Here are the field axioms and resultant lemmas I'm drawing upon in the main Theorem.

**Field Axiom (F1): $a \cdot 1 = a\;\forall a \in F$**

**Field Axiom (F2): $\forall a \in F,\;\exists (-a) \in F: a + (-a) = 0$**

**Field Axiom (F3): $a + 0 = a\;\;\forall a \in F$**

**Field Axiom (F4): $a(b + c) = ab + ac\;\;\forall a,b,c \in F$**

**Field Axiom (F5): $(a + b) + c = a + (b+c)\;\forall a,b,c \in F$**

**Field Axiom (F6): $a+b = b+ a\;\forall a,b \in F$**

**Field Axiom (F7): $a\neq 0 \implies \exists a^{-1}: aa^{-1} = 1$**

**Ordered Field Axiom (O1): $a \leq b \text{ and } c\geq0 \implies ac \leq bc$**

**Ordered Field Axiom (O2): $a \leq b \implies a + c \leq b + c$**

**Lemma (L1): $a\cdot 0 = 0\;\;\forall a \in F$**:

$$ a(1+0) \stackrel{F4}{=} a\cdot 1 + a\cdot 0 \stackrel{F1}{=} a + a\cdot 0 = a(1+0) \stackrel{F3}{=} a\cdot 1 \stackrel{F1}{=}a \implies $$

$$a+a\cdot 0 = a \implies (-a) + a +  a\cdot 0 = (-a) + a   \stackrel{F2}{\implies} 0 + a\cdot 0  = 0$$

$$\stackrel{F3}{\implies} a\cdot 0  = 0\;\;\square$$

**Lemma (L2): $a>0 \implies a^{-1} > 0$**

Assume $a>0, a^{-1} \leq 0 $ then

$$a^{-1} \leq 0 \stackrel{O1}{\implies} aa^{-1} \leq 0\cdot a  \stackrel{F7,L1}{\implies} 1 \leq 0 \stackrel{O1}{\implies} a\cdot 1 \leq a\cdot 0 \stackrel{F1,L1}{\implies} a \leq 0$$

But we assumed $a>0$, therefore $a^{-1} > 0\;\;\square$

**Lemma (L3): $a>b \implies a-b > 0$**

$$a+(-a)>b+(-a) \stackrel{F2}{\implies}  0>b-a\;\;\square$$

**Lemma (L4): $a<b \text{ and } ac < bc \implies c> 0$**

Assume $a<b \text{ and } ac < bc$

$$ac < bc \stackrel{O2}{\implies} ac + (-ac) < bc + (-ac) \stackrel{F2}{\implies} 0 \leq bc + (-ac) \stackrel{F4}{\implies}0 \leq c(b + (-a))$$

Therefore,

$$b>a \stackrel{L3}{\implies} b + (-a) > 0 \stackrel{F2}{\implies}(b + (-a))^{-1} > 0 \stackrel{O1}{\implies}$$
$$0\cdot (b + (-a))^{-1} < c(b + (-a))\cdot (b + (-a))^{-1} \stackrel{F7,L1}{\implies} 0 \leq c\cdot 1 \stackrel{F1}{\implies} 0 < c\;\;\square$$

---

**Theorem: $0<1$**

$$a < b \implies a \stackrel{F1}{=} a\cdot1 < b \stackrel{F1}{=}b\cdot1 \implies a\cdot 1 < b\cdot 1 \stackrel{L4}{\implies} 1>0 \;\;\square$$

Comment: every step here $a \leq b \implies a\cdot1 \leq b \cdot 1 \implies 0\leq 1$ must be justified. In first place I dont see how to justify the last implication.

Comment: @Masacroso first implication is multiplicative identity, third follows from ordered field axioms —do I need to make this explicit?

Comment: yes, you need, as this is how a proof is done.

Comment: @Masacroso gotcha — will revise

Comment: @Masacroso so a lot of proofs in math utilize ordered field theorems without explicitly mentioning them, but since I’m trying to establish these from the ground up I can’t “cheat” and use other field theorems unless I introduce them as a Lemma right?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only ordered field axiom? Does your field has only this property? Wikipedia lists more axioms, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Definitions .

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko -- my proof is WIP --> I'm only calling out the axioms I will use to make the proof self-contained -- so I'm adding as I go. I'm revising my post per the comments above as I practice proofwriting.

Comment: Pardon, but if you change axioms, this is another field and another question. I'm not asking about the proof, but about the formulation of the question. Otherwise you accepted a wrong answer, because it uses other axioms, the ones you did not mention.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko -- an ordered field is an ordered field here -- I should not be changing any axioms. I'm drawing the on the same ordered field axioms we all learn.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko let me finish my revisions (note the "WORK IN PROGRESS") then things should settle out.

Comment: I never learned these axioms. It is a bit strange then that you write one axiom, and not all of them? UPD: fine, please finish this work in progress.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko ok -- see much expanded treatment. This was to make each step justified per Masacroso

Comment: @Bey thanks, now it makes sense! Congratulations with the proof :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $a\cdot 0=0\quad \forall a\in F$
2. $a\cdot 1= a\quad \forall a\in F$

Let $a<0$ then $a\cdot 1<a\cdot 0$

Implies $a\cdot(1-0) <0$

Since $a<0$ and $a\cdot (1-0)<0$

Implies $1-0>0$

Hence $1>0+0=0$

Comment: What if we assume $a>0$?

Comment: $a\cdot 1>a\cdot 0$ implies $a\cdot(1-0) >0$ and $a>0$ implies $1-0>0$ implies $1>0$

Comment: +1 nice — makes sense to me

Comment: Strictly speaking, you used the fact $a > b \Longrightarrow a + c > b + c$, which is a natural axiom, but was not listed in the original question.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko my original goal was to verify MY approach (there are many approaches) -- I liked this one because it was constructive and used just a few axioms. I'm still pushing through my (admittedly less elegant) proof for sake of completeness, but this is the proof I *wished* I had come up with lol

Answer (score 2):

Your proof if fine but it extremely long and much more *complicated* than it needs to be.

The man thing is proving Th:  $x^2 \ge 0$ and $x^2 = 0 \iff x=0$ and $0< 1$ follows as a corollary.

Lemma 1: can be more easily proven via $a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0 = a(0+0) = a\cdot 0$ so $a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0 + (-(a\cdot 0)) = a\cdot 0 + (-(a\cdot 0))$ so $a\cdot 0 + 0 = 0$ and $a\cdot 0 = 0$.

The only three other lemmas you need are:

Lemma B:  $a > 0 \implies -a < 0$.

Proof:  $a > 0 \implies a+(-a) > 0 + (-a) \implies 0 > -a$.

Lemma D:  $-(-a) = a$.
Pf:  $(-a) + a = a+(-a) = 0$ so $-(-a) = a$

Lemma C: $a(-b) = (-a)b = -(ab)$ and $(-a)(-b)=ab$ and $(-a)(-b) = ab$
Pf: $ab + a(-b) = a(b+(-b)) = a\cdot 0 = 0$ and therefore $-(ab) = a(-b)$.  Likewise $ab + (-a)b = (a +(-a))b = 0\cdot b = 0$ and therefore $-(a) =(-a)b$
Finally $(-a)(-b) = -(a(-b))=-(-(ab)) = ab$.

Thereom:  $x^2 \ge 0$ with $x^2 = 0 \iff x=0$.

Pf:  If $x > 0$ then $x\times x > 0 \times x$ and $x^2 > 0$.
if $x=0$ then $x^2 = x\times x = 0 \times 0$ and by Lemma 1 $0\times 0 = 0$.
If $x < 0$ then $0 < -x$ and $(-x)^2 > 0$ and as $(-x)^2 = x^2$ we have $x^2 > 0$.

Corollary:  $1 > 0$.
Pf:  $1 = 1^2$ and $1\ne 0$ so $1^2 > 0$ so $1 > 0$.

Comment: Thank you +1 — yes, this is much more compact :-) I was trying my hand at a proof without resorting to looking at other answers — there are many, many slicker proofs out there but I want to check the clarity (or lack thereof ;-)) when left to my own devices.